# Npm & Node installation

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

[image]

So i've been trying to download and install node.js and npm to  should allow me to run expo on my computer. More especifically the cmd "npm install expo-cli --global". When i run it i get the error(s) below. Now, i'm a novice in terminal and navigation of the computer in general, so i'm having troubles underestanding the errors, or what the solution might be. Any help is appreciated

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally official Docs To solve this issue check it

Answer (score 0):

To install a package globally you have to install with root permissions (similar to "Run As Administrator" on windows). You can run:

```sh
sudo npm install expo-cli --global
```

And enter your password at the prompt (keep in mind that even though it won't show up, it's still there).

---

An alternative solution (if you're not administrator or don't want to use sudo) is giving npm a prefix and adding that to your path. There's a nice guide for that on GitHub: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md